# Errata for 13th Age system for core rulebook since first printing

Tags: 13th-age, errata

I own the kickstarter version of the 13th Age core rulebook. As hinted [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/103257/15652), the SRD contains "very important rule updates and clarifications".

Is there any list of changes available? The original book is too nice to not use it, but at the same time I would certainly prefer to get updated rules in case something is majorly broken in the first printing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you download the SRD (currently on version 3.0) as a single PDF, the revision history starts on page 8. You can use the core book rules just fine, though - nothing's majorly broken. For example, there's a clarification to the Targeting rules that says, "When a spell or power targets a nearby enemy, ally, or creature, you can’t target yourself unless it is explicitly stated that you can also be a target." That's something that could pretty easily be determined at the table, and if the GM decided that a wizard could zap themselves with *lightning fork*, it wouldn't break the game.

An example of a more significant change is the ranger's Animal Companion rules, which were updated in 13 True Ways as part of the druid class. The core book's version of the animal companion rules isn't in the SRD - the newer rules from 13TW are.

Also, check out the [13th Age FAQ](http://site.pelgranepress.com/index.php/13th-age-faq/).

Comment: Any specific part of the 13th Age FAQ we should be checking out that's prompting you to recommend it? It doesn't seem relevant to the errata issue, so if there's some part of it we should be looking at that has you bring it up, it's worth directing our attention to that specific part of the FAQ.

Comment: The asker mentioned rules clarifications in their post, and the Rules FAQ is a good first place to check if the wording on something seems confusing.